# scalaz - using if within for comprehension

Tags: scala, concurrency, monads, scalaz, monad-transformers

I'm trying to achieve the following using EitherT:

```
def op1 : EitherT[Future, String, Int] = ???
def op2 : EitherT[Future, String, Int] = ???

for {
  value1 <- op1
  if value1 > 20
  value2 <- op2
} yield value2
```

But I'm getting this error: `could not find implicit value for parameter ...`

The desired behavior is when op1's return value fails the if condition, EitherT(Future.successful("Failed Validation".left[Int])) is returned, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Did you mean `def op1: EitherT[Future, String, Int] = ???`?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you meant something like this:

```
def op1: EitherT[Future, String, Int] = ???
def op2: EitherT[Future, String, Int] = ???

for {
  value1 <- op1
  value2 <- if (value1 > 20) {
      op2
    } else {
      EitherT(Future.successful("Failed Validation".left[Int]))
    }
} yield value2
```

Comment: this certainly works, but I was hoping for something close to what for comprehension can do for collections, so the if statement can be inline, if that makes sense?

Comment: @BZapper At least I cannot make any sense of it, because the `if`s used directly inside `for`-loops *are not branchings*, they are *filters*. And afair `EitherT` doesn't even have a proper `withFilter`-method, because it doesn't make sense: an `Either` cannot simply "drop" values, whenever something is not `Right`, it *needs* a `Left`. But in the signature of `withFilter`, there isn't even any place for a proper error message to use in a `Left`, it simply returns `false`, and that's it.

Comment: Ah, yes, I follow. I guess then the next best thing would be a handleError function that allows me to do something like onError(_ => EitherT(Future.successful("Failed".left))? But then that's not much better than the if / else anyway. Thanks!